# Stop matplotlib plot from closing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have code for "live" plotting with Matplotlib in Python, but it closes once it's done. I would like the plot to remain open.

Code below

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    plt.ion()
    plt.show()

    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        x = i ** 2
        plt.scatter(i, x)
        plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like [this](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/index.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def make_data():
        for i in range(100):
            yield i, i*2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
color = plt.cm.cubehelix(np.linspace(0.1,0.9,100))
plot, = ax.plot([], [],'o')
xdata, ydata = [], []
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)

def run(data):
    x,y = data
    xdata.append(x)
    ydata.append(y)
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()    
    if y > ymax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, 1+xmax)
        ax.set_ylim(ymin, 1+ymax)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()

    plot.set_color(color[x])
    plot.set_data(xdata,ydata)
    return plot,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,run,make_data,blit=True,interval=10,repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Maybe scatter would be better since it might allow for different colors of each circle.